# How send unicode character to active application?

Tags: macos, sendinput

I need something like SendInput in Windows API.

I see this method, I don't know there is anyway to convert unicode character to virtual Key code.

```
CGEventRef CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent (
   CGEventSourceRef source,
   CGKeyCode virtualKey,
   bool keyDown
);
```

Comment: You can use SendInput to send unicode characters, but you are limited to UTF-8 since you are limited to a short for wScan.  You need to set wVK to 0x00 and set the use unicode flag(0x0004) in dwFlags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CGEventRef e = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(NULL, NULL, true);
CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString(e, unicodeStringLength, unicodeString);   
CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, e);
```

Comment: It doesn't look right to pass `NULL` as the second parameter of `CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent`, because it's not a pointer.  It happens to work, because the `NULL` is treated as zero, which is a valid key code.  Also note that you should say `CFRelease(e)` at the end.